# Set global minimum logging level across all loggers in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, logging

At the time of invocation of my application, I'd like to be able to read in (from config or command line or environment variable) the minimum logging level across ALL of my loggers and then globally set the logging module to respect this MIN_LOGGING_LEVEL.

For example, something like this (which doesn't exist):  `logging.setLevel(logging.INFO)`

I understand that I can individually, on the loggers and on handlers, set the logging levels, as well as create filters for handlers to respect things like the DEBUG flag.  However, what I really want is to be able to change the minimum log level across all loggers at invocation time (and depending on environment, for example).

Do I have to roll this myself and construct the configuration dynamically at runtime to accomplish this? Or is there a better way or pattern that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`logging.disable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) - the following ensures `logging.INFO` and below are disabled:

```
logging.disable(logging.INFO)
```

From the documentation:

> Its effect is to disable all logging calls of severity lvl and below, so that if you call it with a value of INFO, then all INFO and DEBUG events would be discarded, whereas those of severity WARNING and above would be processed according to the logger’s effective level.

To undo it later, you can call:

```
logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)
```

Comment: Is there a similar `enable` function or something?

Comment: @Paul Use this: `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)` that will set the level in whatever file it is placed (assuming the logging module has been imported.) Not *necessarily* a global fix but could be based on one's design.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into something similar, but I went in a different direction. I ended up with...

```
import logging
logging.root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Python loggers work hierarchically, so setting it on the root logger affects all downstream loggers inheriting from it.

In a few other examples, the code, `logging.getLogger()`, also returns the root logger, so the code here is essentially the same as those examples.

With knowledge of the hierarchical nature of loggers, the new information here is that you don't need to set the level globally, on the root. You can be selective while still affecting multiple modules/loggers.

If you use the code `log = logging.getLogger(__name__)` to retrieve your logger in each module, and if you configure your logger inside the `__init__.py` file of a package, you can set the level on that specific logger, affecting all loggers inside that package.

```
 - package_a
   - __init__.py
   - module_a.py
   - module_b.py
 - package_b
   - __init__.py
   - module_c.py
   - module_d.py
```

Say you have packages and modules set up, as is shown above.

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('package_a').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Running this code will make it so module_a.py and module_b.py are now configured to DEBUG level, while module_c and module_d remain unaltered.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to using the disable function, you can override the default level setting of `WARNING` as follows:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)  # choose your level here
```

I wouldn't call this a *global* solution per-se, as it requires a file-level declaration, but it's useful IMO for simple debugging during development before a more cohesive project hierarchy has been established.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: This only sets the logging level for a single logger, not globally across all loggers.